# Value of Inverse of Thermal Voltage

Tags: thermodynamics, units, si-units, boltzmann-equation

I am trying to solve the Poisson-Boltzmann Equations and have come about the constant
$$
\beta = \frac{e}{K_BT}
$$
which Wikipedia denotes as the inverse of Thermal voltage. Now this constant is multiplied by potential $\psi(x)$, and then we compute $\sinh\left(\frac{e\psi}{K_BT}\right)$. If the value of $\beta$ is very high, then the $\sinh()$ explodes. Does anyone know in what units $\beta$ is usually taken? For Hartree atomic units, I get this value as 1059.11484897 for 298.15 K, but I am looking for a smaller value.

Comment: *If the value of $\beta$ is very high, then the $\sinh()$ explodes.* The only thing that matters is the dimensionless value of $\beta\psi$. Why do you care what $\beta$ is?

Comment: I replace $\psi$ with $\psi_r+\psi_0$ where $\psi_0$ is the free space potential. To make $\psi_0$ dimensionless one needs to multiply it with $\beta$ and hence the explosion.

Answer (score 0):

$kT$ has units of energy, so does $eV$ (where $V=\psi(x)$). Of course, $eV/kT$ has to be dimensionless, since it appears in an exponent.

Thus: $\beta\psi(x)$ is dimensionless, making $\beta$ have units of

$$[Volts]^{-1} = [Charge]/[Energy]$$

In SI, that's Coulomb's per Joule, which is small because $e$ is small.

Generally, though, dealing with atoms, the electron volt, eV, literally $(e \times 1\,{\rm V}),$ is more convenient.

A rule of thumb is that room temp is 300 K is $\frac 1 {40}\,$eV, which relates temperature to average kinetic energy.